# get random ads from not viewed ads

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database contains two tables as follows:-

1. **ADS**
   ads_id
   ads_image
   ads_link
2. **ads_viewed**
   adsv_id
   adsv_adsid
   adsv_ip
   adsv_timing

and when any user enters my website the ads loads by AJAX and add the visitor data to "ads_viewed" table

now I want when viewing the ads to display random ads but from not viewed ads.

**EXAMPLE:** If I have four (4) ads,I viewed the ads number:#1 and #2 then it should view me one of these two ads #3,#4 then after finishing showing all ads, start the process from the beginning.

so I want the mysql query to do that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you without showing us any code. Also many people might find "so I want the mysql query to do that." offending. We are not here to write the code/application for you, but rather help you solve a problem.

Comment: According to Stanimir, you should really improve your question with exact table structures (field types, sample values, indexes, etc.) and code blocks that you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Stanimir I wrote the tables structures and I will put now the normal code.thanks to your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do it this way:

```
SELECT adsv_adsid, COUNT(adsv_adsid) as adviews FROM `ads_viewed` WHERE
adsv_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' GROUP BY adsv_adsid ORDER BY adviews LIMIT 2
```

The query will give you the id of the two ads which has been viewed the least number of times. Is that what you want?

Comment: great solution I will add small edit on it by adding another order as the following ( ORDER BY adviews,RAND() )

Comment: If you think that the answer helped you, please select it as accurate :)

Comment: The problem is with that code, that if the `ads_viewed` table doesn't contain any rows for that IP, it will return nothing.

Comment: @Fenistil I tried to put ( GROUP BY "ads_id" ) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the tables and search for NULL values in the second table.

```
SELECT ADS.*, ads_viewed.adsv_id FROM 
ADS LEFT JOIN ads_viewed ON 
((ADS.ads_id=ads_viewed.adsv_adsid) AND (ads_viewed.adsv_ip="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
WHERE ads_viewed.adsv_id IS NULL;
```

But if the user saw all the ads, this query will return an empty set. I think it's better to ORDER and LIMIT the query, this way you always got a result, even if all the ads are visited by that user:

```
SELECT ADS.*, ads_viewed.adsv_id FROM 
ADS LEFT JOIN ads_viewed ON 
((ADS.ads_id=ads_viewed.adsv_adsid) AND (ads_viewed.adsv_ip="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
ORDER BY ads_viewed.adsv_id
LIMIT 1;
```

You can also check here for NULL value to see it was visited or not.

Comment: I will try it now but I see the second code (no problem with limit but I want to order the ads randomly can I ?)